# Django DRF get request query param in custom decorator applied on a function in viewsets.ViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In django rest framework when create a custom viewsets.ViewSet can we apply a custom decorator on a specific function in that ViewSet?

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """
    Example empty viewset demonstrating the standard
    actions that will be handled by a router class.

    If you're using format suffixes, make sure to also include
    the `format=None` keyword argument for each action.
    """

    @permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
    @custom_decorator_1()
    def list(self, request):
        pass

    @custom_decorator_2()
    def create(self, request):
        pass

    @custom_decorator_3()
    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        pass
```

If yes then how can we get query parameters inside that custom decorator applied on a ViewSet? Or is there any alternate solution to achieve this where I can apply multiple decorators on a ViewSet action?

Right now I am trying to do it in this way:

```
def custom_decorator():
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user passes the given test,
    redirecting to the log-in page if necessary. The test should be a callable
    that takes the user object and returns True if the user passes.
    """

    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func)
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):

            role = request.query_params['role']
            
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

Error received:

> AttributeError: 'UserViewSet' object has no attribute 'query_params'

Comment: You seem to be on a right track - just note that you are decorating a method, so the wrapper func takes the viewset's `self` as the first argument. You should adjust the `wrapper` signature and also return `view_func(self, ...)`

Comment: That said, seeing as you check auth-related stuff in your decorator, this is better solved with a custom permission class.

Comment: @MikeRoll any reference where i can find example for adding multiple custom permission classes

Comment: @PritamKadam https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django provides a simple way to use decorators on class based views (this works for DRF as well):

```py
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(login_required) #replace login_required with your own decorator
    def list(self, request):
        pass
```

More info : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class

But in your case, I would rather go for DRF own Permissions system (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/):

```py
from rest_framework import permissions

class CustomerAccessPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.query_params['role'] == "admin" #or whatever as long as it is a boolean
```